# UTF-8 characters in Java Email with Excel as attachment

Tags: java, excel, email, utf-8, email-attachments

I'm working on a legacy application in which i have to send an email with special characters (utf-8) in email body as well as in the attachment (Excel, xls file).

I've tried a lot on this. Special Characters are not shown correctly in the attachment xls file, however in the email body it's shown correctly.

Code snippet that i'm using is as below.

```java
    private void initalizeMailSession()
    {
        java.util.Properties props = new java.util.Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", Properties.MAIL_SMTP_HOST);
        mailSession = Session.getInstance(props);
    }

    public void sendMailUtf8Attachment() throws Exception
    {
        // Send mail for current object

        if(mailSession==null)
            initalizeMailSession();
        MimeMessage mailMsg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        InternetAddress recipient=null;
        
        if(toList==null&&ccList==null&&bccList==null)
        {
            throw new Exception("No Recipents Found");
        }
        if(toList!=null)
        {
            for(String toAddress: toList)
            {
                recipient=new InternetAddress(toAddress);
                mailMsg.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, recipient);
            }
        }
        
        if(sender==null)
            throw new Exception("Sender not found");
        
        InternetAddress sender=new InternetAddress(this.sender);
        mailMsg.setFrom(sender);
        
        mailMsg.setSubject(subject);

        MimeMultipart mult = new MimeMultipart();
        
        MimeBodyPart messagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
        messagePart.setContent(mailMessage, mailType);  
        
        mult.addBodyPart(messagePart);

        MimeBodyPart filePart = new MimeBodyPart();
            
        filePart.setText(message, "UTF-8"); // message string is having html code with Chinese characters in it.
        filePart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.ATTACHMENT);
        filePart.setFileName("attachmen.xls");
        filePart.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");
        filePart.setHeader("Content-Type", HTML);
            
        mult.addBodyPart(filePart);


        mailMsg.setContent(mult);
        
        Transport.send(mailMsg);
        
        System.out.println("Mail send..");
    }
```

Mail Body with Special Characters :

[image: Mail Body with Special Characters]

Mail Attachment XLS file with Special Characters, I've do add the same html body data in the attached xls file.
[image: Email Attachment Xls file content]

Please help how do i achieve this, to correctly show the special characters in the attachment.

Answer (score 0):

try this
Project -> Properties and change the "text file encoding" to UTF-8

Comment: I couldn't find this option in Eclipse.

Comment: In properties under the resource section, it is available